# Multiple Plots in Matplotlib Widget

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, pyqt, qt-designer

I have designed a relatively large application but I am facing a problem in implementing the Matplotlibwidget graphs. This is the snippet of code where I am handling the graph.

The following code only plots the latest plot that of x2 and y2.

Note: here self.GraphWidget is a MatplotlibWidget object implemented using QtDesigner

```
def Toggled(self,CD):

    self.GraphWidget.axes.plot(self.x1,self.y1,label='plot1')
    self.GraphWidget.axes.plot(self.x2,self.y2,label='plot2')        

    self.GraphWidget.axes.set_xscale('log')

    self.GraphWidget.legend()
    self.GraphWidget.draw()
```

The following code (see below) plots both curves on the graph but I'd rather use the above method so that I can give individual labels etc to each curve:

```
def Toggled(self,CD):

    self.GraphWidget.axes.plot(self.x1,self.y1,self.x2,self.y2)


    self.GraphWidget.axes.set_xscale('log')

    self.GraphWidget.legend()
    self.GraphWidget.draw()
```

Comment: make sure you don't have `hold=False` in your code someplace

Comment: @tcaswell no I don't. I'm finding it pretty difficult handling the matplotlib widget that Qt designer created. I don't want to modify the UI code too much by implementing the Matplotlib widget by hard coding it because it's a rather huge application and Qt designer has helped me implement everything else fairly smoothly. I am considering switching over to qwt plot (any suggestions) ? If the above situation can be solved ofcourse I'd like to stick with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try explicitly setting hold:

```
self.GraphWidget.axes.hold(True)
self.GraphWidget.axes.plot(self.x1,self.y1,label='plot1')
self.GraphWidget.axes.plot(self.x2,self.y2,label='plot2')
```